# How to deal with "Breakpoints" when migrating from Material-UI's `makeStyles()` to React-JSS `createUseStyles()`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to migrate from Material-UI's `makeStyles()` to React-JSS `createUseStyles()` and I am curious how to tackle legacy themes that use 'Breakpoints'?  Is there a recommended migration path to ween ourselves of Material-UI's theme Breakpoints?

At this time, I'm leaning towards rewriting the legacy breakpoints to explicit CSS [@media at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). Naturally, this would loose the ability to custom theme Breakpoints sizes, but I can live with that.

e.g. The original breakpoint Styles:

```
{
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    top: "auto !important",
  }
}
```

Becomes:

```
{
  "@media screen and (min-width: 960px)": {
    top: "auto !important",
  }
}
```

Does this seem like the right path to take?

Comment: Are you migrating away from Material-UI? What's the motivation for not wanting to use `theme.breakpoints.up("md")`? If you just want to be independent of the breakpoint values in the theme, you could convert it to `[theme.breakpoints.up(960)]` which seems a little more convenient and less error-prone than writing out the whole media query. If you're trying to get rid of all Material-UI dependencies, you can hard-code the queries or create your own, similar convenience functions for generating the media query based on a width.

Comment: I am simply moving my project to use TypeScript and when researching how to deal with ```makeStyles()``` and Typescript I came across comments that recommended moving too "react-jss" and createUseStyles().  Seemed to be related to plans for Material-UI 5.x?

Comment: All of the documentation examples are in both JavaScript and Typescript and almost every single example leverages `makeStyles` to some degree. I wouldn't jump the gun on making changes in preparation for v5 -- there is still a lot up in the air as far as how the styling solution will change. Even if you do move to `react-jss`, there isn't any reason why you couldn't keep using the `theme.breakpoints.x` functions.